# How do I report a Friedman Test when the sample violates the assumption: 'Group is a random sample from the population'?

Tags: sample, assumptions, friedman-test

How do I report a Friedman Test when the sample violates the assumption: 'Group is a random sample from the population'?

My study involves a group of participants receiving an intervention and a Likert scale being used pre, post and 8 weeks post the intervention.

I have been advised to use a Friedman test. However, my sample is a convenience sample. My participants are a group of young people in a single class from the school that agreed to take part.

This is for my thesis and it's really important that I can clearly justify my decision making and be cautious about how I interpret and generalise the findings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Just my two cents:  I think the best approach is to be clear about how your sample was chosen, and in your conclusions add some caveats about interpreting the results too broadly.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have been (at least somewhat) misled.

As a permutation test, you don't necessarily have to have random sampling from the population for the Friedman test to be a valid test. You have an experiment, so you can get a valid hypothesis test *if you have random assignment to treatment*. You could make a conclusion about the effect of the intervention on that group (since suitable random assignment would make substantive alternative explanations unlikely).

Your difficulty will come in extending your conclusions to a population that doesn't correspond to the group you tested on (e.g. if your sample includes only men or only college students but you want to make a conclusion about all adults, or if you included only 13 and 14 year old students but wanted to make a conclusion also about a wider variety of school ages).

Without data, you'd usually have little basis for saying that your results apply to untested sections of the population.

That would require justification not given by your hypothesis test, and such justification may be all but impossible in your case (it's hard to say), making the conclusion relatively specific.

So it's not that you can't do anything, its that the scope of your conclusions will be highly limited.

If you couch your conclusions in suitable terms (as indicated above) there would be little risk of misrepresenting what you have evidence for.